# How import txt file in sqlite?

Tags: android, file, sqlite, text-files

how can we import data in sqlite with a sqlite's txt file as a backup? Is it better to use a xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLlite database files are portable, there's no particular reason to dump them to text only to reimport them into a database except if you need something human-readable.

Comment: it was the better idee. I save the database in .db and i replace with this. tanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean to import a CSV file (Comma-Separated Values).

I suggest this way!

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

Comment: tank's i prefere to export /import in .db It's easier